# pod install error: The name of the given podspec 'file_picker' doesn't match the expected one 'gx_file_picker'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, pod-install

I'm getting the following error while doing pod install.

```
[!] The name of the given podspec 'file_picker' doesn't match the expected one 'gx_file_picker'
```

I have tried changing the name of the file in 'pubspec.yaml' from gx_file_picker to file_picker but that doesn't seem to work. Further research has not been productive either.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I been facing the same problem, what I found is that gx_file_picker/ios/gx_filepicker.podspec:

```
  s.name             = 'file_picker'
```

must be changed to:

```
  s.name             = 'gx_file_picker'
```

And woudn't do any harm to do this after the change:

1. go into ios folder
2. delete the PodFile.lock file
3. rm -rf Pods
4. pod cache clean --all
5. pod deintegrate
6. pod setup
7. pod install

Now everything works in my project.

Comment: the file is returned back to file_picker after I run pod install then same error happened

Comment: Change again then.

Comment: i did that many times but still the same.

Comment: But if you change the param i mention, and just start the app, do it works? Because it does in my actual project.

Comment: Just to help out a bit, to find this directory "gx_file_picker/ios/gx_filepicker.podspec:" navigate to your installed Flutter SDK folder in finder, ensure you can view hidden folders and navigate to "flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/" you would find the the directory there.

Comment: @birukIS did you follow the other steps listed below which include clearing pod cache. I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Couldn't resolve this by cleaning Pod's cache.
This issue seemingly has connection with pod, but these plugin pods are there because of "flutter pub".
I managed to solve this issue by using the following command:

1. flutter pub cache clean
2. flutter pub get
3. pod install (in .ios folder)